# Illustrator is saving making my solid colours as transparent

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, transparency

The title pretty much says it all.

I've worked with solid colours the entire time, and when I go and save, for some reasons Adobe Illustrator decides to make all my colours and shapes transparent.

On the picture, you will see on the left how the desired effect within illustrator, and on the right the result when I go and save it. It's the same wether I save it as a pdf, jpeg or the illustrated png.

[image]

Comment: Something's wrong with that picture. If you don't want transparency, why are you checking the transparency option?

Answer (score 1):

Check your white objects..... White (paper) in Illustrator has a tendency to be set to **overprint**. Adobe states this is so "gradients and other objects print correctly when white is used". (I'm paraphrasing)

Select the white objects (or select all) and check the **Attributes panel** to ensure the `Overprint` option is **not** checked. And also check the **View Menu** to ensure `Overprint preview` is **not** checked.